# "View with Google Drive" contextual menu item in Finder - how can I make it always appear for files / folders in Drive

Tags: mac, finder, google-drive

I find the ability to right-click a file or folder in the Finder and bring up the option to "View with Google Drive" quite useful (for all files and folders in My Drive).

Sometimes, this item appears and works nicely:

[image: Google Drive menu items visible]

And sometimes, it doesn't appear in the contextual menu at all (on the same folder as the above screenshot):

[image]

I can't discern any rhyme or reason as to why it sometimes appears and sometimes disappears. Under both conditions, Google Drive for Mac was running and up to date with syncing, and I was connected to the Internet.

I want these items to always be visible on files and folders in My Drive from the Finder. How can I achieve this?

Mac OS 10.11.3

Google Drive Version 1.32.4066.7445

Comment: The [relevant official documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2565956?hl=en&ref_topic=6069785) says nothing on the topic. I also [posted the question on the Google Drive Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/X9n7oyndAl8;context-place=forum/drive)